# Is there an alternative link instead of the one in the docker book?

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and was working through the docker book and just got to the building a Sinatra web application part. But the link provided to download the source code doesn't exist. I tried using the GitHub link for the code but that isn't working as well. I need to make a binary executable as the next step and I am unable to do so.

```
$ cd sinatra
$ wget --cut-dirs=3 -nH -r -e robots=off --reject="index.html","
Dockerfile" --no-parent http://dockerbook.com/code/5/sinatra/ webapp/
```

This is what I am supposed to do but if you copy paste the link into your browser, it doesn't work. I also tried making each folder I needed and physically making files but in the next step which is `chmod +x webapp/bin/webapp`, it says that the directory does not exist even though it does.

Comment: It looks like https://dockerbook.com/code/ (check link for reporting errata....) is directing you to https://github.com/turnbullpress/dockerbook-code where all the code seems to be available. Why don't you contact the bookd author for this ? Since you payed he should give the service.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much!